# Does a HashMap use a HashSet to store its keys?

Tags: java, hashmap

I'm wondering if a HashMap uses a HashSet to store its keys. I would guess it does, because a HashMap would correspond with a HashSet, while a TreeMap would correspond with a TreeSet.

I looked at the source code for the HashMap class, and the method returns an AbstractSet that's implemented by some kind of Iterator.

Additionally...when I write

```
    HashMap map = new HashMap();

    if(map.keySet() instanceof HashSet){
        System.out.println("true");
    }
```

The above if statement never runs. Now I'm unsure

Could someone explain how the HashMap stores its keys?

Comment: No, [in the Oracle JDK] it does not. [Look at the implementation (on GrepCode)](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/util/HashMap.java/), which should make it pretty obvious that HashMap does not utilize and underlying HashSet. (Additionally, [from the API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) you can see that HashMap is *not* a subtype of HashSet, nor does it even conform to the Set interface.)

Comment: (Very much to the point, see the `Entry<K,V>[] table = (Entry<K,V>[]) EMPTY_TABLE;` member in HashMap - an array is used, not a HashSet.)

Comment: @user2864740 note your link is to the OpenJDK implementation, not Oracle JDK.

Comment: There is a large overlap between Oracle JDK and OpenJDK. For core classes like java.util they are identical.

Comment: @StuartMarks I'm sure that's generally the case, but there's no guarantee.  At a minimum, it appears the version of `HashMap` on my machine declares its table as `Entry<K,V>[]`, while the linked class on GrepCode is simply `Entry[]`.  I know I've been burned before by confusing OpenJDK and Oracle/Sun JDK, despite how similar they are in theory.

Comment: So you've already looked at the source for `HashMap`, so you know that the answer is NO.  Interestingly, a `HashSet` stores its values as keys in a `HashMap`, but that's a different question.

Comment: @dimo414 The grepcode links show the original JDK 7 GA release from July 2011. There have been a whole series of 7-update releases, plus JDK 8 was released last month. Go to hg.openjdk.java.net for more recent sources. The java.util classes still are virtually identical. I guess the class was generified in one of those releases.

Comment: @dimo414 That is, the difference you see is from evolution of the code in the 7-update and 8 releases, not divergence between OpenJDK and Oracle JDK.

Comment: It's the other way around. Look at the JavaDoc of `HashSet`, it reads: 'This class implements the Set interface, backed by a hash table (actually a HashMap instance)'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're actually asking two different questions:

1. Does a `HashMap` use a `HashSet` to store its keys?
2. Does `HashMap.keySet()` return a `HashSet`?

The answer to both questions is no, and for the same reason, but there's no technical reason preventing either 1. or 2. from being true.

A `HashSet` is actually a wrapper around a `HashMap`; `HashSet` has the following member variable:

```
private transient HashMap<E,Object> map;
```

It populates a `PRESENT` sentinel value as the value of the map when an object is added to the set.

Now a `HashMap` stores it's data in an array of `Entry` objects holding the Key, Value pairs:

```
transient Entry<K,V>[] table;
```

And it's `keySet()` method returns an instance of the inner class `KeySet`:

```
public Set<K> keySet() {
  Set<K> ks = keySet;
  return (ks != null ? ks : (keySet = new KeySet()));
}

private final class KeySet extends AbstractSet<K> {
  // minimal Set implementation to access the keys of the map
}
```

Since `KeySet` is a private inner class, as far as you should be concerned it is simply an arbitrary `Set` implementation.

Like I said, there's no reason this *has* to be the case.  You could absolutely implement a `Map` class that used a `HashSet` internally, and then have your `Map` return a `HashSet` from `.keySet()`.  However this would be inefficient and difficult to code; the existing implementation is both more robust and more efficient than naive `Map`/`Set` implementations.

<sub>Code snippets taken from Oracle JDK 1.7.0_17.  You can view the source of your version of Java inside the `src.zip` file in your Java install directory.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

> I'm wondering if a HashMap uses a HashSet to store its keys.

That would not work too well, because a Set only keeps track of the keys. It has no way to store the associated value mapping.

The opposite (using a Map to store Set elements) is possible, though, and this approach is being used:

`HashSet` is implemented by using a `HashMap` (with a dummy value for all keys).

The set of keys returned by `HashMap#keySet` is implemented by a private inner class (`HashMap.KeySet extends AbstractSet`).

You can study the source for both class, for example on GrepCode: [HashMap](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/util/HashMap.java/) and [HashSet](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/util/HashSet.java/).

> Could someone explain how the HashMap stores its keys?

It uses an array of buckets. Each bucket has a linked list of entries. See also

- [How does Java HashMap store entries internally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9603024/how-does-java-hashmap-store-entries-internally)
- [Hashmap and how this works behind the scene](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19644626/hashmap-and-how-this-works-behind-the-scene)

Comment: In JDK 8, the bucket is converted into a tree if the linked list gets too long.

Comment: See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20485383/1441122) to another question for a description of the policy for switching from a list to a tree.

Answer (score 2):

The set that is returned by the keySet is backed by the underlying map only.

As per javadoc

> Returns a Set view of the keys contained in this map. The set is backed by the map, so changes to the map are reflected in the set, and vice-versa. If the map is modified while an iteration over the set is in progress (except through the iterator's own remove operation), the results of the iteration are undefined. The set supports element removal, which removes the corresponding mapping from the map, via the Iterator.remove, Set.remove, removeAll, retainAll, and clear operations. It does not support the add or addAll operations.
>   Blockquote

HashMap stores keys into buckets. Keys that have same hash code goes into the same bucket. When retrieving value for an key if more than one key is found in the bucket than equals method is used to find the right key and hence the right value.

Answer (score 1):

Answer is: NO.

`HashMap.keySet()` is a **VIEW** of the keys contained in this map.

The data of the map is stored in `Entry[]` table of `HashMap`.